# How to print lines only if next line is not matching using sed or awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have the below pattern in the logs file where a "Starts" is finished with a "Ends" in the next line. I am looking to print only if the next line pattern is not matched with a "Ends", i:e to print all the Starts which are not ended.

```sh
$ egrep AccountResource testlog.txt|egrep "Starts|Ends"
05:20:34.949 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:12345 - Starts
05:20:45.863 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource () - Ends
05:20:46.274 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:12345 - Starts
05:20:46.360 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource () - Ends
05:22:21.703 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:12345 - Starts
05:22:22.680 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:5678 - Starts
05:52:48.578 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:5678 - Starts
05:52:50.673 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource () - Ends
05:52:50.937 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:12345 - Starts
05:52:50.977 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource () - Ends
06:09:35.951 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:5678 - Starts
06:09:36.409 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource () - Ends
06:09:36.690 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:5678 - Starts
06:09:36.720 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource () - Ends
```

below is expected output

```sh
05:22:21.703 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:12345 - Starts
05:22:22.680 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:5678 - Starts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/Starts\n.*Ends$/d;P;D' file
```

Process two lines at a time.

If the first ends in `Starts` and the second ends in `Ends`, delete both.

Otherwise print/delete the first and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a single `awk` for this job:

```sh
awk '!/AccountResource/{next} NR == nl && $NF!="Ends" {print p} $NF=="Starts" {p=$0; nl=NR+1}' testlog.txt

05:22:21.703 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:12345 - Starts
05:22:22.680 INFO  c.b.h.r.rest.Account - AccountResource for account:5678 - Starts
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '
!/AccountResource/ {next}
NR == nl && $NF != "Ends" {print p}
$NF == "Starts" {
   p = $0
   nl = NR+1
}' testlog.txt
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much @anubhava. It worked like a champ. I want to learn sed and awk in detail, could you please where can we get detailed training ?

Comment: @IbrahimPatel see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for learning resources

Comment: For awk: **Effective Awk Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins**

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
!/AccountResource/{ next      }
/AccountResource.*Starts$/{
  if(found && val){ print val }
  found=1
  val=$0
}
/AccountResource.*Ends$/{
  found=0
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
!/AccountResource/{ next      }    ##If a line does not contain AccountResource move cursor to next line.
/AccountResource.*Starts$/{        ##Checking condition if line contains AccountResource and ends with Starts then do following.
  if(found && val){ print val }    ##If found and val both are SET then print val.
  found=1                          ##Setting found to 1 here.
  val=$0                           ##Setting val to current line here.
}
/AccountResource.*Ends$/{          ##Checking condition if line contains AccountResource and ends with Ends then do following.
  found=0                          ##Set found to 0 here.
  val=""                           ##Nullify val here.
}
'  Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @Ibrahim Patel, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with an explanation:

`sed 'N; /Starts\n.*Ends$/ d; P; D' file`

**Command Explanation:**

sed generally works by reading one line at a time and working on that "pattern space". But if you want to look at multiple lines at one time, additional lines can be added to the pattern space.

N; Start of the cycle. Add the next line to the pattern space (pattern space now contains 2 lines).

/Starts\n.*Ends$/ Search (/) the current pattern space for text matching: Starts + newline (\n) + any combination of characters (.*) + Ends + end of line ($). Stop searching (/)

d; If the pattern was found, delete the pattern space (both lines). Start next cycle.

P; Otherwise, print the first line in the current pattern space.

D Delete the first line of the pattern space (pattern space now contains 1 line). Start the next cycle.

Note, the commands p and d print and delete all lines in the current pattern space, respectively. The uppercase versions, P and D, print and delete only the first line (i.e. up to the first newline character).